# Почему не отображается фоновое изображение?

Tags: javascript, css

Перестало отображаться фоновое изображение. Просто пустое поле. Пути все верные . Что может быть не так?

Код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#banner").css({"height":$(window).height() + "px"});

});
```

```css
section #banner {
width:100%;
background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
background-attachment: contain;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='js/script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header></header>

    <section id='banner'>
        
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Селектор вида `section #banner` будет искать тэг `section`, внутри него будет искать объект с айди - `#banner`. У вас же сама секция имеет это айди, поэтому вам достаточно изменить ваш селектор на `section#banner` или как выше подсказали, просто на `#banner`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#banner").css({
    "height": $(window).height() + "px"
  });
});
```

```css
section#banner {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
  background-attachment: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='js/script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <section id='banner'>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Один момент — селектор вида `section#banner` имеет смысл только в том случае, когда мы перебиваем уже имеющийся стиль селектором более высокой специфичности, поскольку айди это и так уникальный селектор.

Answer (score 0):

Не `section #banner {`, а просто `#banner {`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#banner").css({
    "height": $(window).height() + "px"
  });

});
```

```css
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.hersam.com/images/2015/2015-vultr-benchmarks.png');
  background-attachment: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='js/script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header></header>

  <section id='banner'>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```